# Node.js 2 require()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I saw some Node.js code as below with 2 require() together in a statement but don't know what does it means, does anyone know that? thx!

```
const Models = require('mongoose-models')(require('mongoose'));
```

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break up of your query

`const Models = require('mongoose-models')(require('mongoose'));`

This actually equivalent to

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Models = require('mongoose-models')(mongoose);
```

so you are passing the reference of mongoose to mongoose-models.
mongoose-models must require mongoose object to work perfectly.
For readablity, you can use two-step initialization.